# Adding a class to image which is a child of div which may have other tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am currently doing something similar to StackOverflow's system that shows how an answer will look when Markdown is converted to HTML. The part of HTML that is related to this question is

```
<form method='post' class='form-horizontal' role='form'>
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <textarea name="question" id="test" data-iconlibrary="fa" data-provide="markdown" spellcheck='false' rows="10" data-hidden-buttons="cmdPreview cmdHeading cmdCode"></textarea>
    <div id='result' style='border:1px solid grey; border-radius:5px;'></div>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

And also jQuery

```
$('textarea[name=question]').keyup(function() {
    $.post('{{url("web/questions/showPost")}}',{question:$(this).val(),_token:$('input[name=_token]').val()},
        function(result) {
            $('#result').html(result);
        });
    //DOES NOT WORK
    var parentEls = $( "img" ).parents()
        .map(function() {
            return this.id;
        }).get().join(", ");
    alert(parentEls);
});
```

As you can see, I do `$.post` request to my Laravel method and get converted to HTML Markdown from there. Everything works just perfectly. **What I am actually trying to do** is to add `img-responsive` bootstrap classes to all images that are inside of my results div `div#result`.

I know that the easiest way to do this would be simply editing PHP converter I use (`GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Markdown`) and add things I want, **but** because I use Laravel it is a really bad idea to edit vendor files because after an update everything will be lost. So, my idea is to somehow add that class `img-responsive` with jQuery. It first looked simple, because I thought I can do everything with simple `div p img` selector, but then I realized that users need a more *flexible* system that will add that class even if they write something like `div p a strong em img`. So, my first idea was to get all parents from all `img` tags and check, if there is a parent whose id is `result`, and this was what I was trying to do under that comment **`//DOES NOT WORK`**. Actually, there I was trying only to get parents list (I think I would have fixed everything if I got it), but this code only returns me the first `img` parents – so, my logo's parents....

Maybe anyone knows, what could I do to add that class or how to get that parents list? Not only my solution, other solutions will be greatly appreciated (I believe there is a lot better solution than mine to add that class). If you know the solution with Laravel too, without editing vendor, this is even better.

Sorry, if I have missed an answer to my question. My English does not let me to formulate the question in a short way.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

The only way I could make it work (thanks to guys who commented on my post because they pointed out the problem!) was to make an additional hidden div in which I store the data I get from PHP, and then on delay add classes to img and only then put in visible div. Also, because it is reaaaally slow, I decided to do update not on keyup, but when `preview` button is clicked. So thats my code now

```
$(document).on('click','#preview',function() {
    $.post('{{url("web/questions/showPost")}}',{question:$('textarea[name=question]').val(),_token:$('input[name=_token]').val()},
        function(result) {
            $('#hiddentResult').html(result);
            setTimeout(addImgResponsive,100);
        });
});
function addImgResponsive() {
    $('#hiddentResult').find('img').addClass('img-responsive');
    $('#result').html($('#hiddentResult').html());
}
```

Is there a way to fix it `without` using additional div? The answer why I am using a delay is because `$('#hiddentResult').find('img').addClass('img-responsive');` executes too early...

Comment: Can you show us what did you try so far to see if we can detect the problem source :)

Comment: dont do anything just add $('#result').find('img').addClass('img-responsive')

Comment: @Maraboc The code under that comment is what I tried to do to get img parents list

Comment: @RAHULSR sadly, this does not work :( Tried it before

Comment: Surely, whatever you try has got to be in that callback function hasn't it? As it stands, `var parentEls = .....` is just synchronous and will execute too early.

Comment: it does not works since your ajax call is sync hence the response isnt complete yet ...thats why i hate shorthand ajax calls limits your options

Comment: So, is there any way to fix it then? Tried on `setTimeout` but getting a nonsense – class adds for a second and then removes

Comment: @RAHULSR only way I could make it work is to add result from laravel to hidden div and then add that class there, and put html into not hidden result.

Comment: @Danielius, add that solution to your question. I'm sure someone will be able to spot what's going on and offer a better solution.

Comment: If that works, then so should `function(result) { $('#result').html(result).find('img').addClass('img-responsive'); }`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Nope, without a delay, I have the same problem.This is strange, but ech.

Comment: Then something strange is going on. Maybe some DOM mutation observer is interfering.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 what is funny that if i delay by 1 millisecond it works perfectly. without – does not. It's obviously because setTimeout works after last event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was that this guy

`$('#hiddentResult').find('img').addClass('img-responsive');`

worked synchronously with this one

```
$.post('{{url("web/questions/showPost")}}',{question:$('textarea[name=question]').val(),_token:$('input[name=_token]').val()},
    function(result) {
        $('#hiddentResult').html(result);
    });
```

and executed first, before the second one got the results from PHP, I didn't see any effect because no data was loaded. After adding this function

```
function addImgResponsive() {
    $('#hiddentResult').find('img').addClass('img-responsive');
    $('#result').html($('#hiddentResult').html());
}
```

and putting it into `setTimeout(addImgResponsive,0);` to make it work asynchronously, everything now works well. Thank you, **Roamer-1888** and **RAHUL S R**

**EDIT:**
My whole solution looks like that:

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','#preview',function() {
    $.post('{{url("web/questions/showPost")}}',{question:$('textarea[name=question]').val(),_token:$('input[name=_token]').val()},
        function(result) {
            $('#hiddentResult').html(result);
            setTimeout(addImgResponsive,0);
        });
});
function addImgResponsive() {
    $('#hiddentResult').find('img').addClass('img-responsive');
    $('#result').html($('#hiddentResult').html());
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method='post' class='form-horizontal' role='form'>
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <textarea name="question" id="test" data-iconlibrary="fa" data-provide="markdown" spellcheck='false' rows="10" data-hidden-buttons="cmdPreview cmdHeading cmdCode"></textarea>
    <div id='result'></div>
    <div id='hiddentResult' class='hidden'></div>
    <input type='submit'>
    <input type='button' id='preview' value = 'Peržiūrėti'>

</form>
```

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Can you post the *whole* solution please, starting with `$(document).on('click','#preview ...'?`

Comment: It's really hard to see why the setTimeout and the `hiddentResult` double-shuffle should be necessary. It's virtually guaranteed that the double-shuffle isn't necessary, so `$('#result').html(result).find('img').addClass('img-responsive');` should work, and it *should* work without a timeout.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 you are wrong. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779785/4402190). `setTimeout` makes function work _after_ my code is executed (data is successfully taken and put into my hidden div), without it, `$('#result').html(result).find('img').addClass('img-responsi‌​ve');` will execute before hidden div gets data. That makes difference, so it works well.